# Cmake - ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET misunderstanding

Tags: cmake

I'm struggling to learn cmake and right now I'm trying to use the add_custom_target and add_custom_command.

As I understand from the documentation and by googleing around:
The add_custom_target creates a target with a given name that always gets build and executes the specified commands. So I wrote this following snippet:

```
add_custom_target(Name myTarget ALL
 COMMAND message("SomeMessage")
)
```

And expected to see that message when I ran 'cmake' command. However the message is not printed. I have no errors but the message won't print. Also I have tried running 'make' after 'cmake' command but still can't see the message.
From what I understand cmake creates the makefiles and 'make' command actually does the build with those created makefiles. So(from my understanding) the target should be build when running make.

I know it is a basic thing but I googled around and searched on this website and found examples which I thought I understood but still I could not make my simple snippet to work as expected. There is something that I do not get(I'm a total beginner with cmake and makefiles). Please explain to me what am I doing wrong and how can I make that target to be created and execute the given command. Thank you for reading my post!

Comment: Under *COMMAND* option it should be "shell"-command, like `COMMAND echo SomeMessage`. This command will be executed on `make` invocation.

Comment: I have this in my snippet: add_custom_target(Name myTarget ALL
 COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Some string"
). However that string is not printed when I run make. I think the syntax is correct.

Comment: Instead `Name myTarget` it should be `myTarget`: In [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_target.html) command signature uses *non-upper-case* parameter as one which expects some string instead. Only upper-case *OPTIONS* should be provided as is. (But not all upper-case parameters are options; one of exception is `*_VAR` parameters which should be replaced with the variable's name).

Comment: Ok now the target was built :D. I guess I need to be more carefull when reading the documentation. Thanks :D